# Drawing a line with half a circle using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I'm using this piece of code to draw a straight line using `UIBezierPath` class as follows:

```
let myPath = UIBezierPath()
    myPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:10, y:5))
    myPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:100, y:5))

    myPath.close()
    UIColor.blue.set()
    myPath.stroke()
    myPath.fill()
```

however, I don't know how to change this basic drawing to include half a circle in the path to be as follows:

[image]

Comment: Try the addArc method

Answer (score 3):

From: [addArc documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibezierpath/1624367-addarc)

```
myPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 55, y: 5), 
              radius: 10, 
              startAngle: 0, 
              endAngle: CGFloat.pi, 
              clockwise: false)
```

This should give you about the circle you want. You will also need to break your line into 2 segments.